# How to sync Intranet thunderbird light calender

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-lightning

I am using thunderbird with Lighting calendar.Is there any way to sync thundirbird calendar with local network ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a peer-to-peer sync provider for Lightning, but what you can do is set up a CalDAV server on some machine running on your local network. This machine must be always on, or at least on when the other machines are. A quick and easy to set up server is available at http://sabre.io/

Comment: CalDAV sync with all local calendar ? means if i create any event in my local machine then it will save on server and it will display event details in all other intranet machine ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the CalDAV server is on your local network, it will work just the same as normal. Set up all local machines to sync with that CalDAV server.

Comment: Thanks, can I create plugin for which add new calendar and sync with server CalDAV ?. instead of manually configured all the things

Comment: I am working on something like that, it should be ready in nightly builds some time in February or March.